# How to dispatch action whenever state changes in Vuex?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I wish to deploy some actions in vuex whenever a state changes. The only way I can think is by putting a watcher on that state and deploy from there, but I'm not sure if that is the best way. Is there some more elegant way of doing that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use Vuex Plugin. https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/plugins.html

```
const myPlugin = store => {
  // called when the store is initialized
  store.subscribe((mutation, state) => {
    // called after every mutation.
    // The mutation comes in the format of `{ type, payload }`.
  })
}
```

It is the best and recommended way to do this kind of stuff which you are asking about.

When you define the plugin, **remember to register it in the store!**

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  // ...
  plugins: [myPlugin]
})
```